# Elasticsearch terms query: less tags - more relevance

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an index with products. Each product has it's own tags like this

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "tags": ["red", "blue", "green"]
    ...
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "tags": ["red", "blue"]
    ...
},
{
    "_id": 3,
    "tags": ["red"]
    ...
}
```

How do I create a terms query against the "tags" field that considers the amount of tags the object associated with? I'd like to see the following results for the "red" tag query:

```
1: _id=3
2: _id=2
3: _id=1
```

Comment: Dan Tuffery's answer is right and quite straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [script based sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting)

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "script": "doc.containsKey('tags') == false ? 0 : doc['tags'].values.size()",
            "order": "asc",
            "type": "string"
        }
   }
}
```

Security regarding scripts has changed in the more recent versions of ElasticSearch, for more information take a look at this page:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/scripting-security/